# Finding maximum population, and the maximum generations in C, pointers included

Tags: c, pointers, while-loop

I have made a program that will see how fast bacteria can multiply, I use a bacteria container, and see how big it is (in feet), how high the nutrient level is, and what the temperature is that the bacteria will grow in.

the printf for the output of "t" and "maxpop" always outputs 1 for the generations, and population.

My output is this:

```
Welcome to the population growth program...
What is the size of the container (in feet)?
Enter value --> 5

What is the nutrient level coefficient?
Enter value --> 3

What is the incubating temperature (in degree C.)
Enter value --> 33
maximum population reached after 1 generations
maximum population 1
```

The desired output that I want is:

```
Welcome to the population growth program...
What is the size of the container (in feet)?
Enter value --> 22
22 is an unacceptable value for this data...
The value must be between 1 and 8
Enter value --> 0
0 is an unacceptable value for this data...
The value must be between 1 and 8
Enter value --> 8

What is the nutrient level coefficient?
Enter value --> 4
4 is an unacceptable value for this data...
The value must be between 0 and 3
Enter value --> 3

What is the incubating temperature (in degrees C.)
Enter value --> 80
80 is an unacceptable value for this data...
The value must be between 20 and 54
Enter value --> 37

maximum population reached after 91 generations
maximum population 608637958121099264
maximum population reached after 30.33 hours
population reaches 0 after 181 generations
colony lived for 60.33 hours
```

So far this code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int readcont();
int readnutr();
int readtemp();
int getmaxpop(int, int, int, float, int*);

int main(){

    int cont, nutr, temp;
    int N, cont2, temp2, nutr2;
    int t=1, maxpop; 
    float k=0;


    printf("Welcome to the population growth program...\n");
    printf("What is the size of the container (in feet)?\n");

    cont = readcont();  

    printf("\nWhat is the nutrient level coefficient?\n");

    nutr = readnutr();

    printf("\nWhat is the incubating temperature (in degree C.)\n");

    temp = readtemp();
    printf("The feed is: %d \nThe nutrient level is: %d \nThe incubating temperature is: %d\n", cont, nutr, temp);

    temp2 = abs(temp2 = 37 - temp);
    nutr2 = 3 - nutr;
    cont2 = 8 - cont;


    maxpop = getmaxpop(cont2,nutr2,temp2,k,&t);


    printf("maximum population reached after %d generations\n", t);
    printf("maximum population %d\n", maxpop);



    return 0;


}

int readcont(){
    int x = 0;
    while(x < 1 || x > 8){
        printf("Enter value --> ");
        scanf("%d", &x);

        if(x < 1 || x > 8){
            printf("%d is an unacceptable value for this data...\n", x);
            printf("The value must be between 1 and 8\n");
        }
    }
    return x;   
}

int readnutr(){
    int x;
    while(x < 0 || x > 3){  
        printf("Enter value --> ");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        if(x < 0 || x > 3){
            printf("%d is an unacceptable value for this data...\n", x);
            printf("The value must be between 0 and 3\n");
        }
    }
    return x;
}

int readtemp(){
    int x;
    while(x < 20 || x > 54){        
        printf("Enter value --> ");
        scanf("%d", &x);

        if(x < 20 || x > 54){
            printf("%d is an unacceptable value for this data...\n", x);
            printf("The value must be between 20 and 54\n");
        }
    }
    return x;
}

int getmaxpop(int cont, int nutr, int temp, float k, int *t){
    int maxpop = 1, currpop = 1;

    for(*t =2 ; currpop < maxpop; *t++){
        maxpop = currpop;

        k = 0.005+(cont*0.003)+(nutr*0.004825)+(temp*0.001);
        currpop = 1 * pow(2.71828, ((1 - k) * (*t)));
    }
    *t--;
    return maxpop;
    return *t;
}
```

Comment: If `k` is a constant, you don't need to recalculate it each time through the loop. Also your formula for `currpop` is increasing exponentially; there is no maximum... `currpop = 1 * pow(2.71828, ((1 - k) * (*t)));` is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: I want to see the population die as well, thats why I put it there, is the equation that I wrote incorrect?

Comment: The formula has the form of an exponential growth. As `t` increases `currpop` will increase forever. Why should the population die? Does the nutrient level get used up? Does the temperature increase and kill them? Should the container limit growth? These effects are not considered in this formula. Also the population at time t+1 usually depends on the population at time t.

Answer (score 1):

Your `getmaxpop` function is equivalent to

```
int getmaxpop(int cont, int nutr, int temp, float k, int *t)
{
    int maxpop = 1, currpop = 1;

    for(;currpop < maxpop;)
    {
        // never happens because currpop is not less than maxpop
    }
    return maypop;  // always returns 1
}
```

Comment: Do you have any clue as to how I can make it the proper output? Because I saw that and to be honest I am drawing a blank, I have been working on this for a while now.

Comment: The code you have attempts to compute the time it takes to reach a target population, but you need to compute the target first. You must have been given an equation for calculating the maximum population, and I don't know what that would be.

Comment: t is the generations, to calculate the population it is currpop is the getmaxpop function

Comment: @AsadMahmood look at the condition `currpop < maxpop`  since at the entry you set both to 1  this condition is false, so the program never enters the for loop.   You need to set currpop = 0 ... your logic inside the forloop is incorrect too.  it won't give you the maximum population.

Comment: What can I do to get the max population? I have been trying and messing around, I have been only coding for not even 2 and a half months, so I know it's not the best :(

Comment: @AsadMahmood That's not a coding question or even a mathematical question, it's a biology question. In real life, the bacteria either fill the entire space, or the bacteria consume all of the available nutrients. So it's up to you to decide what limits the bacteria population.